# How can I test a child component on Jest/Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a child component since test coverage says I am missing it.

This is the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { map, keys, pick } from 'lodash';
import TableExpandedRowItem from './TableExpandedRow';

const TableExpandedRowWrapper = ({ rowClassProp, shipmentItem }) => {
  const itemKeys = pick(shipmentItem, [
    'description',
    'originationAddress',
    'receivingAddress',
  ]);

  return (
    <div className={rowClassProp}>
      {map(keys(itemKeys), itemKey => (
        <TableExpandedRowItem
          key={shipmentItem[itemKey]}
          dataTitle={shipmentItem[itemKey]}
          rowValue={shipmentItem[itemKey]}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

TableExpandedRowWrapper.propTypes = {
  rowClassProp: PropTypes.string,
  shipmentItem: PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
};

TableExpandedRowWrapper.defaultProps = {
  rowClassProp: 'row',
};

export default TableExpandedRowWrapper;
```

And I am trying to test `TableExpandedRowItem` but it says its length is `0`.

This is the test I have so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import TableExpandedRowWrapper from '../../TableExpandedRowWrapper';
import TableExpandedRowItem from '../../TableExpandedRow';

describe('TableExpandedRowWrapper component', () => {
  let props;

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      rowClassProp: 'row',
      shipmentItem: {},
    };
  });

  it('renders TableExpandedRowWrapper', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<TableExpandedRowWrapper {...props} />);

    expect(TableExpandedRowWrapper).toBeDefined();
    expect(wrapper.find('.row')).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(TableExpandedRowItem).toBeDefined();
    expect(wrapper.find(TableExpandedRowItem)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

This is the whole error:

```
 FAIL  src/client/pages/Shipments/__tests__/components/TableExpandedRowWrapper-test.js
  TableExpandedRowWrapper component
    ✕ renders TableExpandedRowWrapper (58ms)

  ● TableExpandedRowWrapper component › renders TableExpandedRowWrapper

    expect(received).toHaveLength(length)

    Expected value to have length:
      1
    Received:
      {Symbol(enzyme.__unrendered__): null, Symbol(enzyme.__renderer__): {"batchedUpdates": [Function batchedUpdates], "getNode": [Function getNode], "render": [Function render], "simulateError": [Function simulateError], "simulateEvent": [Function simulateEvent], "unmount": [Function unmount]}, Symbol(enzyme.__root__): {Symbol(enzyme.__unrendered__): <TableExpandedRowWrapper rowClassProp="row" shipmentItem={{}} />, Symbol(enzyme.__renderer__): {"batchedUpdates": [Function batchedUpdates], "getNode": [Function getNode], "render": [Function render], "simulateError": [Function simulateError], "simulateEvent": [Function simulateEvent], "unmount": [Function unmount]}, Symbol(enzyme.__root__): [Circular], Symbol(enzyme.__node__): {"instance": null, "key": undefined, "nodeType": "function", "props": {"rowClassProp": "row", "shipmentItem": {}}, "ref": null, "rendered": {"instance": <div class="row" />, "key": undefined, "nodeType": "host", "props": {"children": [], "className": "row"}, "ref": null, "rendered": [[]], "type": "div"}, "type": [Function TableExpandedRowWrapper]}, Symbol(enzyme.__nodes__): [{"instance": null, "key": undefined, "nodeType": "function", "props": {"rowClassProp": "row", "shipmentItem": {}}, "ref": null, "rendered": {"instance": <div class="row" />, "key": undefined, "nodeType": "host", "props": {"children": [], "className": "row"}, "ref": null, "rendered": [[]], "type": "div"}, "type": [Function TableExpandedRowWrapper]}], Symbol(enzyme.__options__): {"adapter": {"options": {"enableComponentDidUpdateOnSetState": true, "lifecycles": {"componentDidUpdate": {"onSetState": true}, "getDerivedStateFromProps": true, "getSnapshotBeforeUpdate": true, "setState": {"skipsComponentDidUpdateOnNullish": true}}}}}}, Symbol(enzyme.__node__): undefined, Symbol(enzyme.__nodes__): [], Symbol(enzyme.__rootNodes__): [{"instance": null, "key": undefined, "nodeType": "function", "props": {"rowClassProp": "row", "shipmentItem": {}}, "ref": null, "rendered": {"instance": <div class="row" />, "key": undefined, "nodeType": "host", "props": {"children": [], "className": "row"}, "ref": null, "rendered": [[]], "type": "div"}, "type": [Function TableExpandedRowWrapper]}], Symbol(enzyme.__options__): {"adapter": {"options": {"enableComponentDidUpdateOnSetState": true, "lifecycles": {"componentDidUpdate": {"onSetState": true}, "getDerivedStateFromProps": true, "getSnapshotBeforeUpdate": true, "setState": {"skipsComponentDidUpdateOnNullish": true}}}}}}
    received.length:
      0

      20 |     expect(wrapper.find('.row')).toHaveLength(1);
      21 |     expect(TableExpandedRowItem).toBeDefined();
    > 22 |     expect(wrapper.find(TableExpandedRowItem)).toHaveLength(1);
         |                                                ^
      23 |   });
      24 | });
      25 | 

      at Object.toHaveLength (src/client/pages/Shipments/__tests__/components/TableExpandedRowWrapper-test.js:22:48)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the definition of TableExpandedRowItem, but my first guess is that the initial props shouldn't contain an empty `shipmentItem` object, but it should actually contain some keys.

You are mounting the component in the test, so it should render it's children, but if you see this piece from the output, it's clear that the child was not rendered `"rendered": {"instance": <div class="row" />, "key": undefined, "nodeType": "host", "props": {"children": [], "className": "row"}, "ref": null...`

Try adding some dummy data in the `shipmentItem`.